# エクスプローラー内で、リンクができません

Tags: html, vscode

自分で作った(html)ウェブをエクスプローラー内で開いて、そこから同じウェブ内のファイルにリンクしたいのですが、「このページはひょうじできません」とでてきて、リンクされません。
どうすれば、リンクできますか。
ちなみに、visual studio codeでhtmlをかいてます。
これをInternet Exploreで開いて、/boards/india.html/　の部分をクリックすると表示されません。(ちなみに、/boards/india.html/　の部分は、すでにコードは書き終わってます。)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>    
    <title>indiachan</title>

    <style type='text/css'>
        body {font-family : arial,helvetica,sans-serif; color : rgb(30,30,30);  font-size: 14px;background-color: rgb(240,240,240); }
        h1 { font-size: 26px; text-align: center; }
        h3 { font-size: 16px; margin : 3px;  }
        #what_is { max-width : 600px; background-color: #fff; border : 1px solid #444; padding : 10px; margin: auto; }
        #board_select { max-width: 700px; background-color: #fff; border : 1px solid #444; padding : 10px; margin : auto; margin-top: 20px; t    ext-align: center; line-height: 200%; }
        #board_select_inner a { margin-left : 5px;  margin-right: 5px; }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
<div id='about'>

    <h1>Welcome to Indiachan.</h1>
    <div id='what_is'>
        <p>
        Indiachan is a simple image-based bulletin board where anyone can post comments and share images about any topic. You do not need to     register an account for posting. Indiachan will not use cookies or third party ads.
        </p>
        <p>
        See <a href='/rules_and_faq.html/'>rules and faq</a> to learn more about using this site. And yes, this site is inspired by 4chan :)
        </p>
    </div>
</div>

<div id='board_select'>
    <h3>boards : </h3>
    <div id='board_select_inner'>   
        <a href='/boards/india.html/'>India</a> <a href='/boards/b.html/'>Random</a> <a href='/boards/a/'>Anime &amp; Manga</a> <a href='/boa    rds/meta/'>meta</a> <a href='/boards/japan.html/'></a>japan</a> <br>
    </div>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: これだけでは、「普通にリンクすればリンクできます」としか答えようがないです。
URL の階層や「自分で作った(html)ウェブ」のコードを質問文に追記お願いします。
質問文の下に「編集」というリンクがありますので、それをクリックすると編集できるようになります。

Comment: 質問する場合は回答する人が同じ問題を再現できるように詳しい手順や環境を説明すると良いと思います。客観的に質問を見て同じ状況を再現出来るか考えてみると良いかもしれません。

Answer (score 1):

別ファイルへのリンク部分が以下の様に記述されていますが、いくつかの余計な`/`が原因だと思います。

```
<a href='/boards/india.html/'>India</a>
```

リンク先ファイル名の先頭に`/`を付けるとそのファイルは**絶対パス**として解釈されますが、恐らく実際のファイルは相対パスで参照するべきなので、以下いずれかの記述方法になるはずです。
ちなみにファイル名(`*.html`)の後ろについている`/`も余計かと思います。

```
<a href='./boards/india.html'>India</a>
<a href='boards/india.html'>India</a>
```

Comment: 実際のファイル構成が分からないので何とも言えませんが、絶対パスで指定すること自体はよくあるので、問題ではないかもしれませんね。

Comment: できました！！本当にありがとうございます。

Comment: 後、もう一つお願いがあります。

Comment: 返信の[Post Reply]を押してもコメントらが出てこないのですが、どうすればいいですか。ちなみに、php が必要かと思い、phpのファイルをつくたっのですがそうすると、PHP executable not found. Install PHP 7 and add it to your PATH or set the php.executablePath setting　と表示されて、https://www.sumirelab.com/docs/tech/php/visual-studio-codeを使ったphpの開発環境の構築/　　このサイトの通りに行っていたら、Pathの設定のところで躓きました。説明すると、"php.validate.enable": true,のところにPathを入力できません。どうすればいいですか。

Comment: 追加の質問は`PHP`に関するもののようなので、新しい質問に分けたほうがよいと思います。

Comment: 新しい質問ができないので、ここでお願いします！！

Comment: @名無しさん [こちらに引っかかりましたか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)質問ができない場合は日を改めて下さい。質問内容が広くなる場合、別のことを質問したい場合は質問できないとしても新しく質問を立てるべきです。